# How to create Effective Indexing on MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

Can anyone help me on how could i create an index so that my query will execute smoothly.

Currently, I have the below query that returns 8k+ or records. But it takes 2 sec or more to complete. The current records on tblproduction is 16million+

```
SELECT COUNT(fldglobalid) AS PackagesDone
  FROM tblproduction
 WHERE fldemployeeno = 'APD100401'
   AND fldstarttime BETWEEN '2013-08-14 07:18:06' AND '2013-08-14 16:01:58'
   AND fldshift = 'B'
   AND fldprojectgroup = 'FTO'
   AND fldGlobalID <> 0;
```

I have below current indexes but it still query executes longer

```
Index_1
  fldEmployeeNo
  fldStartTime

Index_2
  fldEmployeeNo
  fldTask
  fldTaskStatus

Index_3
  fldGlobalId
  fldProjectGroup

Index_4
  fldGlobalId
```

I have used all of this indexes using FORCE_Index but still the query executes longer.

Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This started as a comment Gordon Linoff's answer but is getting too long.

`It would be better to include fldGlobalId in the index as well` - no it would not - this is counter productive for performance - it won't improve the speed of retrieving the data (queries are not used for inequalities) but will lead to more frequent index updates, hence increased index fragmentation (hence potentially worsening the performance of SELECT) and reduced performance for inserts and updates.

Ideally you should design your schema to optimize *all* the queries - which is rather a large task, but since you've only provided one....

The query as it stands will only use a single index for resolution, hence the index should include all the fields which have predicates in the query *except for non-matches* (i.e. fldGlobalID).

The order of the fields is important: in the absence of other queries with different sets of predicates, then the fields with the highest relative cardinality should come first. It's rather hard to know what this is without analysing the data (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field)/COUNT(*) FROM yourtable) but at a guess the order should be fldstarttime, fldemployeeno, fldprojectgroup, fldshift

If there is a dependency on fldshift from fldemployeeno (i.e. employees always, or at least more than around 90% of the time) then including fldshift in the index is merely increasing it's size and not making it any more efficient.

You didn't say what type of index you're using - btrees work will with ranges, hashes with inequalities. Since the highest cardinality predicate here is using a range, then a btree index will be much more efficient than a hash based index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one index.  Here is the query, slightly rearranged:

```
SELECT COUNT(fldglobalid) AS PackagesDone
  FROM tblproduction
 WHERE fldemployeeno = 'APD100401'
   AND fldshift = 'B'
   AND fldprojectgroup = 'FTO'
   AND fldstarttime BETWEEN '2013-08-14 07:18:06' AND '2013-08-14 16:01:58'
   AND fldGlobalID <> 0;
```

(I just moved the equality conditions together to the top of the `where` clause).

The query should make use of an index on `tblproduction(fldemployeeno, fldshift, fldprojectgroup, fldstarttime)`.  It would be better to include `fldGlobalId` in the index as well, so the index "covers" the query (all columns in the query are in the index).  So, try this index:

```
tblproduction(fldemployeeno, fldshift, fldprojectgroup, fldstarttime, fldGlobalID)
```

Comment: hi, just a little question. why fields on WHERE conditions rearranged? Is there an issue on the arrangement of fields? Or is there a pattern on making WHERE condition?

Comment: @Bryan . . . There is no material reason at all.  When designing an index, you want to put the equality conditions as the first fields in the index.  By rearranging the query, I could just be sure that I didn't miss any.